# Programming in Haskell via Opengl and GLUT

Tags: opengl, haskell, import

Every time I try to compile and run a tutorial that I have found, I get a message saying either "Could not find module GL" or "Could not find module GLUT." I have tried replacing "import GLUT" with "import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL" and "import Graphics.UI.GLUT", but this just causes even more errors. Should "import GLUT" do something, or is it just pseudo code that I'm misinterpreting?

Comment: Have you run `cabal install opengl` and `cabal install glut`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GLUT` and `OpenGL` are *both* needed to run an OpenGL application. This isn't C where importing one will import the other.

So, you need to import the libraries like this:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
```

The following code will then create a simple OpenGL window that simply flushes the command buffer on each render, to check if the program works:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  (progname, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= flush
  mainLoop
```

Compile the program with:

```
ghc --make program.hs
```

If this doesn't succeed, it means that you didn't install the Haskell Platform correctly, and you need to check that the OpenGL packages are correctly installed.

Comment: So if a tutorial program has improt GLUT as the first line, I should put both import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL and import Graphics.UI.GLUT instead?