# how to dynamic to add widget to window such as increase number of vbox in gtk2hs and how to add opengl as a widget in gtk2hs window

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

1. i search Data.Dynamic

how to make use of it to dynamic add widget to increase

```
bgBac1 <- imageNewFromFile "example1_big.png"
row0  <- hBoxNew False 2
boxPackStart row0 bgBac1 PackNatural 0
```

2. how to add opengl as a widget in gtk2hs window ?
   after search it need GtkGLext, but i have installation problem,
   i search this method, however the createwindow is not a widget can not be added to vbox
   [Programming in Haskell via Opengl and GLUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548816/programming-in-haskell-via-opengl-and-glut)

Comment: i return false solved this

Comment: then please close this or add your solution as an answer

Comment: i change to another useful question instead of easy question